# I made custom query with DQL and the object doesn't see that method

Tags: php, symfony, oop, doctrine, dql

When I was learning Symfony, I got a problem with the custom query in DQL, there is a link to the doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-with-dql-or-sql
I made the same function like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\CatPost;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

/**
 * @method CatPost|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method CatPost|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method CatPost[]    findAll()
 * @method CatPost[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class CatPostRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, CatPost::class);
    }

    public function findAllCategoriesConnectedToPost($id) :array
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

        $query = $entityManager->createQuery(
            'SELECT cat.id_cat 
             FROM App\Entity\CatPost cat 
             WHERE cat.id_post = :idPost'
        );
        $query->setParameter('idPost', $id);

        return $query->execute();
    }
}
```

Entity class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CatPostRepository")
 */
class CatPost
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id_post;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id_cat;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getIdPost(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_post;
    }

    public function setIdPost(int $id_post): self
    {
        $this->id_post = $id_post;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdCat(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_cat;
    }

    public function setIdCat(int $id_cat): self
    {
        $this->id_cat = $id_cat;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And then I want to use it in my controller like this:

```
/App/Controller/ArticleController

$categories = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository(CatPost::class)
->findAllCategoriesConnectedToPost($id);

var_dump($categories);
die();
```

As the result, I got empty array and PhpStorm is telling me that "Method not found" 
Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Could you show us the code from `CatPost` class?

Comment: You should post your full entity and the full action of your controller

Comment: To me it looks good. Try adding var_dump($id) in your controller

Comment: With $id is everything alright because I get it from url "/article/edit/{id}"

Comment: You should post the full method of your controller

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to link to your repository in your entity?

```
/**
* CatPost
*
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CatPostRepository")
*/
class CatPost
```

You can see this on the same doc page further up - https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class

Comment: Yes, I linked it, If You can check this now, please, I added full files of my repository and entity

Comment: @OskarG what method does it say is missing?

Comment: "Method 'findAllCategoriesConnectedToPost' not found in \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Referenced method is not found in subject class." Full msg from phpstorm

Comment: ok, there are a few reasons for that warning so we can just ignore that for now. A good thing to do when having sql problems is to simplify your query and see if that works. Try referencing the table in a different way, `SELECT * FROM cat_posts WHERE id_post = :idPost` assuming your db name is `cat_posts`